# Как в mesh renderer установить текстуру

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо в Компонент Mesh Renderer установить текстуру из папки. Но ничего не выходит.Возможно загрузку не правильно делаю, а может и фунцию не правильную использую.

```
            Object gObject = Resources.Load("Assets/Resources/Materials/scan.mat");
            Texture2D texture_box = (Texture2D)gObject;
            var image = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
            image.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0].SetTexture(1,texture_box);
            OnTrackingFound(mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName);
```

Comment: А вы точно понимаете, что вы делаете? Вы пытаетесь материал привести к текстуре...

Comment: У вас остались какие-то вопросы или все решено?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да честно говоря материал так и не заработал.

Comment: Ну и вы решили просто забить на вопрос без каких-то либо пояснений?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, я преобразовываю в материал какую то картинку. И потом я ее присваиваю Объекту Quad. Присваиваю material необходимый материал но при инициализации ОбЪект имеет стандартную текстуру

Comment: @RiotBr3aker по свойству кстати материал присвоен. Но не отображается

Comment: Вы точно мой код используете?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да. Но я решил по другому, сделать. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю, в каких папках у вас лежат текстуры и материалы, но, допустим, пути такие:

```
Assets/Resources/Materials/material.mat
Assets/Resources/Textures/texture.bmp
```

Загрузка текстуры из ресурсов и ее присвоение материалу:

```
var texture = Resources.Load("Textures/texture") as Texture;
var imageQuad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
imageQuad .GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTexture(1, texture);
```

Загрузка материала и присвоение его материалу:

```
var material = Resources.Load("Materials/material") as Material;
var imageQuad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
imageQuad .GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = material;
```